# Count number of triangles in Sierpinski's triangle

Tags: java

I am supposed to modified this Sierpinski's triangle program to count the number of triangles. So i tried to increment count every time it make a triangle, but, somehow my count doesn't increment.

```
public class SierpinskiTriangle extends Applet 
{  

    public int SeirpTri(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int n, int count)  
    {
        this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
        this.setSize(700, 500);
        if ( n == 0 )
        {
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);     // if n = 0 draw the triangle
            g.drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3);
            g.drawLine(x3, y3, x1, y1);        
            return 1;     
        }

        int xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc;   // make 3 new triangles by connecting the midpoints of
        xa = (x1 + x2) / 2;             //. the previous triangle 
        ya = (y1 + y2) / 2;
        xb = (x1 + x3) / 2;
        yb = (y1 + y3) / 2;
        xc = (x2 + x3) / 2;
        yc = (y2 + y3) / 2; 
        SeirpTri(g, x1, y1, xa, ya, xb, yb, n - 1, count++);   // recursively call the function using the 3 triangles
        SeirpTri(g, xa, ya, x2, y2, xc, yc, n - 1, count++);
        SeirpTri(g, xb, yb, xc, yc, x3, y3, n - 1, count++);
        return count;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)    
    {
        int recursions = 3;
        int count=1;
        // call the recursive function sending in the number of recursions
        SeirpTri(g, 319, 0, 0, 479, 639, 479, recursions, count);

        // Counting triangles using math algorithm;
        int count2 = 1;
        if (recursions ==0) {
            count2 =1;
        }
        else {
            count2 = (int) Math.pow(3,(recursions-1)) * 3;
        }
        System.out.println("Correct answer is: " +count2);
        System.out.println("Answer using recurvise is: " +count*3);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Isn't the answer 'infinity'? :-)

Comment: Might be easier to use a global static variable to track the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `count`, but never look at the result of calling `SeirpTri`.

Instead of:

```
SeirpTri(g, x1, y1, xa, ya, xb, yb, n - 1, count++);   // recursively call the function using the 3 triangles
SeirpTri(g, xa, ya, x2, y2, xc, yc, n - 1, count++);
SeirpTri(g, xb, yb, xc, yc, x3, y3, n - 1, count++);
return count;
```

try something like:

```
return
    SeirpTri(g, x1, y1, xa, ya, xb, yb, n - 1)
    + SeirpTri(g, xa, ya, x2, y2, xc, yc, n - 1)
    + SeirpTri(g, xb, yb, xc, yc, x3, y3, n - 1);
```

You don't need the count parameter at all. Each `SeirpTri` invocation only needs to know aboult the triangles it and its "children" (on the call tree) have created. The "root" call (in `paint`) will return the grand total.

Answer (score 0):

Every param is passed by value in Java.  This means that any changes to `count` will only be local to the method, and not change the `count` object which is passed into the method from the parent method.

You can (and your code has) get around this by returning the `count` param. All you need to do is set `count` in your parent method.

Replace each line:

```
SeirpTri(...);
```

with:

```
count = SeirpTri(...);
```